# Dropbox API Email Notifications

Tags: dropbox-api

Good day,

We use dropbox api for file requests to get files from many people. However, this ends up sending a lot of emails. Is there a way to turn the email notifications off? I checked the api and there doesn't seem to be a parameter for that.

Kind regards,

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to disable the file request emails via the Dropbox API, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.